# jquery set all elements in a given class the same html

Tags: jquery, class, set, each

I have a page with several total fields. They all share the "totalAmount" class.

I need to set the same value in all these fields with jquery:

```
var amt = some value; 
$('.totamAmount').each // - Some instruction to set the value to amt;
```

Comment: What type of elements are the "fields"? input type=text?

Comment: There are a bunch of idiots putting neg. votes here! SO is the place to ask people who knows, even for the most simple questions. If you guys are putting me down for asking then why does SO exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply with [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('.totamAmount').val('{the value you want here}');
```

If they're not form elements, use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('.totamAmount').text('{the value you want here}');
```

Comment: YES!.. And it works with ".html" the same way. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all input fields then you can just do this:

```
$(".totamAmount").val(amt);
```